# Deluge/Twisted script hangs after reactor.run()

Tags: python, twisted, rpc, reactor, twisted.internet

This is a simple example script from [dev.deluge-torrent.org](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Development/UiClient1.2) for interacting with the Deluge API.

Nothing happens after reactor.run() and I don't get the "Connection was successful" message, it just hangs forever.

I ran this on my Ubuntu machine where it works fine, but I couldn't get it to work on my Windows machine where i really want to put it to use.

```
from deluge.ui.client import client
# Import the reactor module from Twisted - this is for our mainloop
from twisted.internet import reactor

# Set up the logger to print out errors
from deluge.log import setupLogger
setupLogger()

# Connect to a daemon running on the localhost
# We get a Deferred object from this method and we use this to know if and when
# the connection succeeded or failed.
d = client.connect()

# We create a callback function to be called upon a successful connection
def on_connect_success(result):
    print "Connection was successful!"
    print "result:", result
    # Disconnect from the daemon once we successfully connect
    client.disconnect()
    # Stop the twisted main loop and exit
    reactor.stop()

# We add the callback to the Deferred object we got from connect()
d.addCallback(on_connect_success)

# We create another callback function to be called when an error is encountered
def on_connect_fail(result):
    print "Connection failed!"
    print "result:", result

# We add the callback (in this case it's an errback, for error)
d.addErrback(on_connect_fail)

# Run the twisted main loop to make everything go
reactor.run()
```

I have no idea of how to go about debugging this issue. I'm very new to Twisted, and from what I understand it's a huge library.